# Jackson Trasformation json data in bean

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a problem with the transformation of json in bean whene the bean have a date.
The client send, for example, the date 2018-07-13 11:30:00 and jasckson store in the bean the date 2018-07-13 13:30:00.

Can you help me?

I'm using spring-boot 1.5.10 and jackson 1.9.10

Answer (score 0):

Try create a `@Configuration` class and ad this 2 bean definitions:

```
@Bean
    public JavaTimeModule timeModule(DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter){
        JavaTimeModule timeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        timeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));
        timeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));
        return timeModule;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(JavaTimeModule timeModule) {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
                .featuresToEnable(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS)
                .featuresToDisable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .modules(timeModule)
                .build();
    }
```